# Prove that the matrix 1 1 1 -1-1-1 1 1 0 is nilpotent and find its invariants

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove that the matrix 1 1 1 -1-1-1 1 1 0 is nilpotent and

find its invariants.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax to format your equations. Also, please show your work. What did you try, and where are you stuck?